# Python --- Split DataFrame column names into multiple columns names based on dictionary having values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'animals': 'deer', 'devices': 'phone', 'movies': 'inseption'},
    index=[1]
)         
col_map = OrderedDict(
    {
        'animals': ['aquatic_animals', 'land_animals'], 
        'devices': ['Tech'], 
        'movies': ['cinemas']
    }
)
df2 = df.rename(columns=col_map)
```

### Output

[image: Actual output]

### Desired Output

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [['beer', 10], ['whiskey', 40], ['vodka', 50]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b'])
print('Input df')
display(df)
col_map = {'a':['liquor'],'b':['percentage','%']}
col_map_fil = {}
for k,v in col_map.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        for i in v:
            df[i] = df[k]
        df.pop(k)
    else:
        col_map_fil.update({k:v[0]})
df = df.rename(columns=col_map_fil)
print('Output df')
display(df)
```